# The Vue Semantic Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Currently I'm getting the following error opening a workspace that didn't happened before.

```bash
The Vue Semantic Server server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted. See the output for more information
```

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'package.json')
> at Object.h [as fileExists] (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\vue.volar-1.8.2\dist\server.js:77:1416)
> at Proxy.x (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\vue.volar-1.8.2\dist\server.js:76:37698)
> at Object.fileExists (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.2.20230626\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:141524:40)
> at host.fileExists (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.2.20230626\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:117617:43)
> at Object.fileExists (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.2.20230626\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:121155:30)
> at getPackageJsonInfo (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.2.20230626\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40622:33)
> at loadNodeModuleFromDirectory (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.2.20230626\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40454:47)
> at nodeLoadModuleByRelativeName (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.2.20230626\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40328:14)
> at loader (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.2.20230626\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40223:78)
> at tryLoadModuleUsingBaseUrl (c:\Users\vinic.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next-5.2.20230626\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40050:12)

Do you have any idea why this started to happen?

Comment: interestingly, I tried googling for part of the error message and found nothing with my particular query: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22TypeError%3A+Cannot+read+properties+of+undefined+%28reading+%27package.json%27%29+at+Object.h+%5Bas+fileExists%5D%22+%22vue.volar%22+%22server.js%22+%22at+Proxy.x%22